# How does rpsec's "let" use memoization?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, memoization

It says in "[RSpec Core 3.5](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)":

> Use `let` to define a memoized helper method

I don't find their example very clear.  Are they saying that the expression for `:count` is only evaluated once for a spec, and again between every spec?

I'm interested particularly in understanding how memoization with `let` would work with an ActiveRecord object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", especially "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". Grammar is important on Stack Overflow. We're creating a reference book so please put in the effort to use spell checking and proper formatting.

Answer (score 4):

> Are they saying that the expression for :count is only evaluated once
>   for a spec, and again between every spec?

answer from [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let):

> The value will be cached across multiple calls in the same example but
>   not across examples.

So yes, it will be evaluated once for every example.

In other words the value will be evaluated once per `it` block.

I find their example super expressive, look:

```
$count = 0
RSpec.describe "let" do
  let(:count) { $count += 1 }

  # count will not change no matter how many times we reference it in this it block
  it "memoizes the value" do
    expect(count).to eq(1) # evaluated (set to 1)
    expect(count).to eq(1) # did not change (still 1)
  end

  # count will be set to 2 and remain 2 untill the end of the block
  it "is not cached across examples" do
    expect(count).to eq(2) # evaluated in new it block
  end
end
```

We referenced `count` twice in `memoizes the value` example, but it was evaluated only once.